# password autenthication issues with postgress port connection

Tags: python, postgresql, docker

```
docker run -it
   -e POSTGRES_USER="rootone"
   -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD="rootone"
   -e POSTGRES_DB="ny_taxione"
   -v
```

```
c:/Users/pc/Desktop/airflow_data_eng/toyosiairflowprojects/nytaxione_taxi_postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data `
   -p 5433:5432 `
   postgres:13
```

PS

```
C:\Users\pc\Desktop\airflow_data_eng\toyosiairflowprojects\docker_setup> pgcli -h localhost -p 5432 -u toyosione -d ny_taxione
Password for toyosione:
```

#after entering the password, I keep getting this error. I have reinstalled, changed ports, etc.

```
connection failed: :1), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "toyosione"
```

does anyone know what I can do?

I wanted to create a table and use a website file in my Postgres.

Comment: try `pgcli -h localhost -p 5433 -u toyosione -d ny_taxione`?

Comment: How did you create that user?

Comment: You told it to create the user "rootone", so that is who you have to log in as.  You can't log in as "toyosione" unless you create that user.

Comment: thanks . i cant even remeber anymore the details . it was a long break in bewtween . will just bin the whole project